# Console Write to cursor position

Tags: c#, console

I'm drawing a cross in the console. Here's my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 320; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Convert.ToInt32(x / 4),Convert.ToInt32(y / 4));

        if (x == 160)
        {
            if (y == 50)
            {
                Console.Write("┼");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("│");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (y == 50)
            {
                Console.Write("─");
            }
        }                    
    }               
}
```

The console draws the cross except the middle "┼" symbol. When I debugged the program it hit the  `Console.Write("┼");` line. Instead the program written the "─" symbol. What I'm doing wrong and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are writing to each location multiple times because of the part where you divide by 4.

When (x, y) is (160, 50) you write a cross at (40, 12). Then (x, y) is (160, 51) so you write a vertical pipe at the same location, overwriting the cross. Then later when (x, y) becomes (161, 50) you overwrite the pipe with a dash.

Try this instead:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 12);
    Console.Write("─");
}

for (int y = 0; y < 25; y++)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(40, y);
    Console.Write("|");
}

Console.SetCursorPosition(40, 12);
Console.Write("┼");
```

Comment: The dividing is essential to my program to be able to show bigger values. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: @Cobold what do you need more than a simple math?

Comment: @L.B I'm plotting a graph, so I need values bigger than (80,25).

Comment: See my updated answer. You can plot values larger than 80 on your graph, just remember to scale them first.

Comment: @Cobold `I'm plotting a graph, so I need values bigger than (80,25)` I say the same. Use some math to map bigger values to 80x25

Comment: @Cobold you don't need the division when you're just drawing the axes.  You can follow the suggested technique here and retain whatever scaling code you have for the actual plot.